# Admin text panel ignores html tags and paragraphs

Tags: django, django-admin, django-filter

For some reason content column in admin panel does not react to any html tags and new paragraphs.

[Here is example of my text in admin panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXA6S.png)

[This is how it displayed in page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Em0ks.jpg)

my code in models.py:

```
# coding: utf-8
from django.db import models

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255) 
    datetime = models.DateTimeField() 
    content = models.TextField(max_length=10000) 

def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return '/blog/%i/' % self.id
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from blog.models import Post
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView
from registration.views import RegistrationView
from django.contrib.auth import logout

# Create your views here.

class PostsListView(ListView):
    model = Post                    

class PostDetailView(DetailView):   
    model = Post

def logout_view(request):
    logout(request)
```

Comment: Where is this code `text{{ value|linebreaks }}text`? And what behavior are you expecting? And what is "built-in filters in admin panel"?

Comment: can we see the views.py  think thats the most important part

Comment: @AntoinePinsard, i was wrong about that. I thought about [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#built-in-filter-reference), but i can use it only in templates

Comment: The admin panel doesn't allow that by default. You'll need a custom editor to do that. [This](https://github.com/pydanny-archive/django-wysiwyg) might help you. If you don't want to install a different app, you can do it by wrapping your content with `<p>Some Text</p><p>Some Text</p>` and then using `{% autoescape off %}{{your.content}}{% endautoescape %}` to display raw HTML content.

Comment: @KeenanLawrence thank you! that's what i need.

Comment: It's a pleasure. Because I'm new to Stack Overflow, please accept my answer.  It's a duplicate of my comment with an added example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The admin panel doesn't allow that by default. You'll need a custom editor to do that. [This](https://github.com/pydanny-archive/django-wysiwyg) might help you. If you don't want to install a different app, you can do it by wrapping your content with

`<p>Some Text</p><p>Some Text</p>`

and then using

`{% autoescape off %}{{your.content}}{% endautoescape %}`

to display raw HTML content.

eg.

```
{% autoescape off %}
    <p>Some text </p><p>Some text </p>
{% endautoescape  %}
```